# How to push an ingested deep link back to a web browser on Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm currently having trouble where I am ingesting a deep link in my application, but after further review of the URL, I want to push the URL back to the web browser to display since my application does not provide the capability of using it. When I try to open the URL in a web browser, nothing happens since I have it defined to be a deep link. I tried sanitizing in the manifest with android:pathPrefix="/#!/foo", but the # character is not supported and causes the whole thing to not work.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.IntentForwardingActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:scheme="https"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**IntentForwardingActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        handleDeepLinking(data.toString());
    }
}

private void handleDeepLinking(String url) {
    Intent intent;
    if (url.contains("/#!/foo")) {
        intent = HomeActivity.newIntentForFoo(this, url);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: `#` character defines a hash (in the URI specification) and isn't part of the path. Don't mis-use it.

Comment: @SimonMarquis how would I specify "/#!/foo" in this case then?

Comment: You can't since hash cannot be filtered with android intent-filter mechanism

Comment: @SimonMarquis is there a way I can user pathPattern to get around this?